# First time through idiom

Tags: language-agnostic

This is a classic problem where a list of elements must be processed but the first must be handled differently from the rest. For example printing a string so that each two characters have a dash between.

Here is a fairly horrible example

```
    char *text = "hello";

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(text); i++) {

            if (i == 0) {
                    printf("%c", text[i]);
            } else {
                    printf("-%c", text[i]);
            }
    }
```

Output:

```
h-e-l-l-o
```

First of all, is there a common name for this situation so I can look it up properly?

Second, of course, what is a better way of dealing with this kind of problem? "Better" being either fewer lines of code, faster runtime or lower memory overhead (preferably a happy compromise between them).

Post example code in any language.

Comment: In python your example is a simple "-".join(list(text))

Comment: I don't know python, can you provide a link to this API call, one that explains how it works and its inherent complexity?

Comment: So, .join is a method on the String class. It takes a single list (array) as an argument, and interpolates the string in between items in the list. The list function, when passed a string returns a list of characters. See the answer I'm getting ready to post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sticking with the original C you've written, it's generally best when possible to leave special cases out of the loop, as loops are meant for repetition of the same task. I would write the code as:

```
char *text = "hello";

printf("%c", text[0]);
for (int i = 1; i < strlen(text); i++){
    printf("-%c", text[i]);
}
```

Often the last might also be a special case in which case, you would loop until `strlen(text) - 1`. Of course, if you're using a language with API's that specifically deal with this problem, then use them like in @TylerEaves answer. I'm not aware of any specific name for this kind of problem, but whenever you adjust loop bounds, always be careful of an [off-by-one error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error).

Comment: What if we're working with an array of some other type? We now need to check if the array is empty before accessing the first element. This method feels a bit of a kludge to me. It's better than branching inside a loop though, I'll give you that.

Comment: @user2675345 Good point, hadn't considered if the array was empty. Normally then, I would do a check before using the zeroth element. I admit that makes it less ideal, but we have to expect it to be a bit more kludgy, since now we have to deal with more possibilities. Of course, high-level APIs often abstract these details away and are cleaner to use when they're available.

Answer (score 0):

In python your example is a simple "-".join(list(text))

So, .join is a method on the String class. It takes a single list (array) as an argument, and interpolates the string in between items in the list. The list function, when passed a string returns a list of characters.

Interpreter session expanding my comment

```
>>> test = "this is a string"
>>> list(test)
['t', 'h', 'i', 's', ' ', 'i', 's', ' ', 'a', ' ', 's', 't', 'r', 'i', 'n', 'g']
>>> "-".join(list(test))
't-h-i-s- -i-s- -a- -s-t-r-i-n-g'
```

Comment: It is possible that python implementation of join is hiding the idiom. But it is still there, underneath a language facility.

Comment: When i said language agnostic I meant if someone has a crazy functional way of doing it that only works in Haskell or something then please post. I'm not really interested in "There's a Python library for that", especially if you can't tell me how it works under the hood.